# Tkinter window is hanging inside while loop

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, freeze

I was writing a piece of code when, the tkinter window started hanging. I also noticed that, it only hanged when inside the while loop. This is the code:

```
    # This part dont have any problem
    import random
    from tkinter import *
    import time
    
    ques = 2
    ques_count = ques

    
    root = Tk()
    
    def random_math_generator():
        operators = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
        a = random.randint(1, 9)
        b = random.randint(1, 9)
        operator = random.choice(operators)
    
        return a, operator, b
    
    label = Label(root, text="")
    
    label.pack()
   
    
    # This loop got the problem
    while ques_count != 0:
    
        x = random_math_generator()

        label["text"] = f"{x[0]} {x[1]} {x[2]}= "
        root.update()


    root.mainloop()
```

I also think that root.update is causing the problem.
It would be great to get a good reply.

Comment: There's no code to change the value of `ques_count`, so the loop will never terminate.

Comment: you see, in your code `ques_count` is not being changed at all, its a constant 2 and 2 is not equals to 0 so the loop, never terminates, right?